# ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles minification OK but there is NO obfuscation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, obfuscation, bundling-and-minification, yui-compressor

I have problem with asp.net MVC4 javascript bundles.
All is working and it's OK, but js code is only minimized and NOT obfuscated.
Is there anything I can do in .NET, or should I get back to my own bundling and minification system based on YUI compressor?

Comment: Have you looked at or used https://www.nuget.org/packages/YUICompressor.NET? I'm not aware of the ASP.NET bundling including obfuscation.

Comment: I used it in earlier versions of MVC, but I believed that I won't need it anymore with asp.net MVC 4 where bundling and minification was presented, looks like I was wrong, I found solution now in https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Yui/1.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I installed this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Yui/1.8.0
Works excellent. Saved me some time.

Comment: this only does minification of the libraries... use uglify lib instead

Answer (score 2):

Here is some explanation about bundling and minification in some quick notes.

**Bundling** picks all the scripts/css files and puts them in a single file to make less HTTP requests when loading a page.

**Minification** deletes all useless characters like: spaces, newlines, etc. to decrease file size.

**Obfuscation** pick the readable css or js files and makes it unreadable for the human eye making it more difficult to copy.

So for obfuscation in .Net i recomend:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.UglifyJs/

Answer (score 0):

In file App_Start\BundleConfig method RegisterBundles at the end add the following code:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Also make sure that bundling and minimizations are not disabled from the configuration file.

Comment: This will only minify javascript and do some optimization to javascript code, but it won't obfuscate code. As I see it obfuscation is not supported, I must use YUICompressor.NET